# Modified topologist's sine curve is not a regular submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I was looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459164/topologists-sine-curve-not-a-regular-submanifold-of-mathbbr2) and I could not understand the accepted answer. For some context this question comes as an example in Tu's Introduction To Manifolds and in his example 9.3 he claims the graph of $f(x)=sin(1/x)$ unioned with the interval $I=\{(0,y)\in \mathbb{R^{2}} : -1<y<1\}$ is not a regular submanifold.

The things I do not understand:

1. Why does $\phi(U)\backslash (X\backslash C)$ only intersect the X-axis in one component
2. Why is this a contradiction to $\phi(U)$ intersecting the X-axis in multiple components
3. Why does this contradiction show that there is no adaptive chart U such that $U\cap S$ is the preimage of the X or Y axis intersect $\phi(U)$.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential point of the answer is that for each "sufficiently small" open neighborhood $U$ of $p = (0,y) \in I$ the intersection $U \cap S$ has infinitely many components. "Sufficiently small" means that $U \subset \mathbb R \times (-1,1)$.

Obviously $(\mathbb R \times (-1,1)) \cap S$ has infinitely many components. Each $U \subset \mathbb R \times (-1,1)$ contains some open box $B = (-r,r) \times (a,b)$ with $y \in (a,b) \subset (-1,1)$. Also $B \cap S$ has infinitely many components. Consider the function $\gamma$ associating to each component $B'$ of $B \cap S$ the component $R'$ of the bigger space $(\mathbb R \times (-1,1)) \cap S$ such that $B' \subset R'$. This function is injective (drawing a picture helps to see this).

Now each component $B'$ of $B \cap S$ is contained in a unique component $U'$ of the bigger space $U \cap S$. Each of these $U'$ is contained in a unique component $R'$ of the bigger space $(\mathbb R \times (-1,1)) \cap S$. Clearly $R' = \gamma(B')$ since $B' \subset R'$. This shows that $U \cap S$ must have infinitely components because otherwise the image of $\gamma$ would be finite.

In the answer it is assumed that there is an adapted chart $\phi : U \to \phi(U)$ around $p \in I$. We may assume that $U$ is sufficiently small (otherwise restrict $\phi$ to  $U \cap (\mathbb R \times (-1,1)$).

The set $U$ is shrinked as follows:

Let $C$ denote the component of $\phi(U) \cap X$ containing $\phi(p)$. Since $\phi(U)$ is open, $\phi(U)\cap X$ is open in $X$. But $X\approx\mathbb R$ is locally connected, therefore components of open subsets are open. Thus $C$ is open in $X$ and $X \setminus C$ is closed in $X$. Since $X$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$, $X \setminus C$ is closed in $\mathbb R^2$ and $V' = \phi(U) \setminus (X \setminus C)$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$. Since $\phi(p) \in C$, we see that $\phi(p) \in V' \subset \phi(U)$.

$\phi$ restricts to a homeomorphism
$$\psi : V = \phi^{-1}(V') \xrightarrow{\phi} V' .$$
$V$ is an open neigborhood of $p = \phi^{-1}(\phi(p))$. It is again sufficiently small because it is contained in $U$.

By construction $\psi(V) \cap X = V' \cap X = C$. We claim that $\psi^{-1}(C) = V \cap S$. This results in a contradiction: The set $\psi^{-1}(C)$ is connected, thus $V \cap S$ has only one component which is impossible.

$\psi^{-1}(C) = V \cap S$ is equivalent to $C = \psi(V \cap S) = \phi(V \cap S)$. But
$$\phi(V \cap S) = \phi(V \cap U \cap S) = \phi(V) \cap \phi(U \cap S) = V' \cap \phi(U) \cap X \\= (\phi(U) \setminus (X \setminus C)) \cap \phi(U) \cap X = X \setminus (X \setminus C) = C .$$

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response!